# Debugging information for 'App.Exe' cannot be found or does not match. Binary was not build with debug information

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-8, winrt-xaml, crash-dumps

I have submitted the windows 8 app in store, but the app is failed with crash. They sent crash report called triageddump.dmp, i debug that file in VS as what they instructed me as how to debug with that error report, but i got a result as following,
 "Debugging information for 'App.Exe'  cannot be found or does not match. Binary was not build with debug information."
 i have no clue for this as how to reproduce the error from source. is there any idea for how to workaround with this error report would be more help full. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What it means is that you did not include the debugging symbols. If you build your app in debug mode, you can manually point it to the debug symbols that were created, so long as you have not further obfuscated it before putting it in the store. There are some guides here and there such as [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2014/01/13/debugging-a-windows-8-1-store-app-crash-dump.aspx) that go over getting information out of the triage dumps.

Comment: i am not mean that, i mean the triageddump.dmp file does not support myapp.exe while i debug with that file in VS2012, once the symbols were loaded it give the error that i mentioned in my question.

Comment: I had the same problem with C++ and VS2013. And I enable Generate Debug Info in the C++ property page (Visual Studio 2013) under Linker --> Debugging --> Generate Debug Info = Yes (/DEBUG)